# I have data with column names as dates and I need to unpivot this columns into Dates column and values. How can i get this in oracle SQL developer

Tags: query, oracle-sql-developer

so my input_table is

[image]

This is to be unpivot the columns of dates into Date and Values as in the output

[image]

What is the oracle SQL developer code I need to write to achieve this output table. Please help me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following test tables and data :

```
create table foo (
KPI varchar(50),
DIMENSION varchar(50),
FILTER varchar(50),
"01/05/2023" integer,
"02/05/2023" integer,
"03/05/2023" integer,
"04/05/2023" integer,
"05/05/2023" integer,
"06/05/2023" integer,
"07/05/2023" integer);

insert into foo values ('Impression', 'Sessions', 'Mobile', 1, null, 0, 2, 3, null, 5);
insert into foo values ('Weather', null, 'Laptop', 0, null, null, 4, 8, 2, null);
insert into foo values ('Organic', 'Season', null, 7, null, 8, 0, 7, 4, null);
```

I create a pivot table that will be used to cross join table foo :

```
create table pivot (dates date);
insert into pivot (dates) select to_date('01/05/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY') from dual;
insert into pivot (dates) select to_date('02/05/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY') from dual;
insert into pivot (dates) select to_date('03/05/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY') from dual;
insert into pivot (dates) select to_date('04/05/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY') from dual;
insert into pivot (dates) select to_date('05/05/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY') from dual;
insert into pivot (dates) select to_date('06/05/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY') from dual;
insert into pivot (dates) select to_date('07/05/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY') from dual;
```

And here is the query :

```
select f.kpi, f.dimension, f.filter, p.dates,
       case p.dates
            when to_date('01/05/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY') then f."01/05/2023"
            when to_date('02/05/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY') then f."02/05/2023"
            when to_date('03/05/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY') then f."03/05/2023"
            when to_date('04/05/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY') then f."04/05/2023"
            when to_date('05/05/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY') then f."05/05/2023"
            when to_date('06/05/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY') then f."06/05/2023"
            when to_date('07/05/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY') then f."07/05/2023"
       end as val
from foo f cross join pivot p
order by f.kpi, p.dates;
```

And here is the result set :

```
    kpi     | dimension | filter |        dates         | val
------------+-----------+--------+----------------------+-----
 Impression | Sessions  | Mobile | 2023-05-01T00:00:00Z |   1
 Impression | Sessions  | Mobile | 2023-05-02T00:00:00Z |
 Impression | Sessions  | Mobile | 2023-05-03T00:00:00Z |   0
 Impression | Sessions  | Mobile | 2023-05-04T00:00:00Z |   2
 Impression | Sessions  | Mobile | 2023-05-05T00:00:00Z |   3
 Impression | Sessions  | Mobile | 2023-05-06T00:00:00Z |
 Impression | Sessions  | Mobile | 2023-05-07T00:00:00Z |   5
 Organic    | Season    |        | 2023-05-01T00:00:00Z |   7
 Organic    | Season    |        | 2023-05-02T00:00:00Z |
 Organic    | Season    |        | 2023-05-03T00:00:00Z |   8
 Organic    | Season    |        | 2023-05-04T00:00:00Z |   0
 Organic    | Season    |        | 2023-05-05T00:00:00Z |   7
 Organic    | Season    |        | 2023-05-06T00:00:00Z |   4
 Organic    | Season    |        | 2023-05-07T00:00:00Z |
 Weather    |           | Laptop | 2023-05-01T00:00:00Z |   0
 Weather    |           | Laptop | 2023-05-02T00:00:00Z |
 Weather    |           | Laptop | 2023-05-03T00:00:00Z |
 Weather    |           | Laptop | 2023-05-04T00:00:00Z |   4
 Weather    |           | Laptop | 2023-05-05T00:00:00Z |   8
 Weather    |           | Laptop | 2023-05-06T00:00:00Z |   2
 Weather    |           | Laptop | 2023-05-07T00:00:00Z |
```

Comment: Thanks and it works.